# In JavaScript, given an input string, create a function that returns an array containing an n number of 2d arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to get the `console.log` output at the bottom of the sample code. Currently, my code is returning `undefined`. I would like to know which part I did wrong.

I would also like to know if there are other, more efficient approaches in solving the problem.

```
function pairElement(str) {

  return str.split('')
    .forEach(function(element){
      return element.split('').map(function(pair){
        if (pair == "G") {return ["G","C"];}
        else if (pair == "C") {return ["C","G"];}
        else if (pair == "T") {return ["T","A"];}
        else {return ["A","T"];}
      });
    });
}

console.log(pairElement("ATCG"));
// -> Should be [["A","T"], ["T","A"], ["C","G"], ["G","C"]]
// -> But currently, it is returning undefined
```

Comment: Why are you splitting it twice?

Comment: I think the first split makes the "ATCG" input into ["ATCG"]. The second split then makes it into [["A"], ["T"], ["C"], ["G"]], creating the 2-layers deep array that I need. Then I think need to push or return based on the index of the layer-1 array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do `.split` twice. Here's a possible solution:

```
function pairElement(input){
    var pairs = { A: "T", T: "A", C: "G", G: "C" };
    return input.split("").map(char => [char, pairs[char]]);  // ES6 arrow function
}

console.log(pairElement("ATCG"));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/rko590je/)

---

`"ATCG".split("")` turns the string into an array `["A", "T", "C", "G"]`. Then by applying a mapping function we can transform the output, character by character, into predefined pairs `[["A","T"], ["T","A"], ["C","G"], ["G","C"]]`.

Comment: Accepting this as the correct answer since it **demonstrates how key/value pairs can be used instead of if/else statements**. Thanks. I learned a new technique because of this.

Comment: Trivial optimization: Since it could be static, move the pairs var outside the function so you're not creating it every time the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

What's returned is `str.split('').forEach(...)`. The forEach iterator method does not return anything; it simply runs for every item in the split array.

Perhaps you meant to `.map(...)` instead? This would take the returned values from the callback function and create a new array with them.

Answer (score 1):

You're splitting too many times and you don't need the foreach.  The split creates an array of from the string, (i.e. `["A","T","C","G"]`).  The map then creates a new array with each element modified according to your function (i.e. `"A"` becomes `["A","T"]`)

```
function pairElement(str) {
    return str.split('').map(function(element){
        if (element == "G") {return ["G","C"];}
        else if (element == "C") {return ["C","G"];}
        else if (element == "T") {return ["T","A"];}
        else {return ["A","T"];}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **.map** instead **.forEach**. The .forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.